# Create array of an array's properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    'prop1': 'hello world',
    'prop2': false
  },
  {
    'prop1': 'asdf asdf',
    'prop2': true
  },
  {
    'prop1': 'bob ross',
    'prop2': false
  }
]
```

And now I want to create a new array that just lists one of the properties, for example:

```
createArrayFromProperties(array, item.prop1);

↓ Output ↓

['hello world', 'asdf asdf', 'bob ross']
```

Is this possible to do with a built in JS method, or do I have to use a loop?

Comment: `Array.prototype.map()` i would say

Comment: `arr.map(el => el.prop1)`

Comment: @Vohuman Awesome, thanks

Comment: Please note the code snippet uses an arrow function, if you are not using an ES6 transpiler, use a regular function instead, as the accepted answer of the duplicate question.